# Can't change 'cart' to be 'basket' in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried adding this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 
'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
 add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );   

 function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'Add to basket', 'woocommerce' );
 }
```

To functions PHP, but as you can still see by this page, only some of the text has changed to 'basket'

[Page with 'cart'](http://twinklewinkle.co.uk/newsite/wordpress/shop/)

However, on the other page it seems to have worked:
[Working page](http://twinklewinkle.co.uk/newsite/wordpress/product/new-baby-and-infant-blanket-fox-in-the-forest-glade-autumn-and-winter-edition/)

Why won't it change on the other page (the text), but on the single product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another line to your code -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text',999 );
```

Comment: Added, but no change.

Comment: Perfect, legend.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {

            return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
        }
```

Try this filter